# Is there any use for dyadic hooks in J?

Tags: j

It occurs to me that a dyadic hook has the same effect as the same verbs without the parentheses, e.g.,

```
2 (+ #) 1 2 3
2 + # 1 2 3
```

These both produce the same result: `5`. What can I do with `(+ #)` that I can't do with `+ #`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the big difference is that you can use hooks tacitly to build more complex verbs. The hook becomes a module that you can drop into a longer fork. Removing parentheses takes away the functionality of the hook.

```
   2 (+ #) 1 2 3
5
```

This allows me to pad out a list with 2 more zeros

```
   2 ((+ #){. ]) 1 2 3
1 2 3 0 0
```

This gives a different result

```
   2 (+ # {. ]) 1 2 3
3 4 5
```

Comment: Obvious in hindsight, and of course I've done it myself, but it didn't occur to me when I asked the question.

Comment: However, outside of composition, I can't see much use for dyadic hooks.

Comment: In tacit programming the composition  aspect is a pretty big deal though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Dyadic hook solves the composition "problem" where M stands for a monadic verb, and D a dyadic verb.

```
  M@D
  (D M)
```

Dyadic hook is more necessary than the monadic version which is just a short cut for

```
  (] D M)
```

though dyadic hook can also be modeled as

```
  ([ D M@:])
```

which is also an ambivalent expression.  An example:

```
 (, *~)
```

monadically, appends y and its square
dyadically, appends x and the product of x and y.

(oops, bob is right).  Correct ambivalent verb with above explanations.

```
 ([ , *~)
```

Comment: Actually dyadically x (, *~) y appends x to the square of y